# Let $F$ be the set of all functions $f : \{0,1\} \rightarrow \mathbb N$. Prove that $F$ is countable.

Tags: combinatorics

***Question***:

Let $F$ be the set of all functions $f : \{0,1\} \rightarrow \mathbb N$ . Prove that $F$ is countable.

***Is my proof sufficient to prove that F is countable?*** NB: My university does not consider 0 ∈ ℕ.

Proof:

$F$ is countable if $|F| = |\mathbb N| = \aleph_0$. Thus to show that $F$ is countable we must show that a bijection exists from $F$ to $\mathbb N$.

Let elements of $F$ be of the form $f_i$ where $i \ge 1$. Thus define the function $h : \mathbb N \rightarrow F$ which is defined by the rule $h(i) = f_i$. $h$ is onto since every $f_i$ will eventually be mapped to. $h$ is injective since every function in $F$ is mapped to at most once. Thus $h$ is bijective and so $|F| = |\mathbb N| = \aleph_0$ which means $F$ is countable.

Comment: didn't u assumed that F is countable while saying "Let elements of F be of the form $f_i$ $ i \in N $ ?

Comment: @Presage Damn you're right!

Comment: Notice, that in F, there are functions from {0,1}, so they have only 2 values in domain. You can easily construct a bijection from N x N to F. Just h(n,m) = "such function f in F, so that f(0) = n, f(1) = m". Can you go from there?

Comment: @Presage Well I can prove ℕ x ℕ is countable fortunately. So if we let h : ℕ x ℕ --> F be a function which is defined by the rule h maps (n,m) to the function in F which maps 0 is to n and 1 maps to m. Thus h is evidently a bijection and so |F| = |ℕ x ℕ| = |ℕ|. Thus F is countable. To me it is immediately obvious that h is a bijection from ℕ x ℕ to F. But what do you think? Do I need to prove that h is a surjective and injective?

Comment: To me it is obvious, too. Hovewer sometimes obvious things are the harder to prove. Showing h is injective is easy, cause taking different pairs $(n_1,m_1), (n_2,m_2)$ where either $n_1 \neq n_2$ or $m_1 \neq m_2$, then u definitelly get different function in F (if for example $n_1 \neq n_2$ then for the first pair function $f_1$ maps 0 to $n_1$, and for the second pair, 0 to $n_2$. Showing it is surjective isn't much harder. Just take any function in $f \in F$ It clearly attains some value at 0 and 1, say $f(0)=n, f(1)=m$. Now take pair $(n,m)$ and we are done.

Comment: @Presage Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\xi : F\longrightarrow \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ by 
$$\xi(f)=(f(0),f(1)).$$

Then $\xi$ is bijective since if $\xi(f)=\xi(g)$, then

$(f(0),f(1))=(g(0),g(1))$ implies $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f(1)=g(1)$. Therefore $f=g$

and If $(m,n)\in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, Choose $f\in F$ such that $f(0)=m, f(1)=n.$

Hence $\xi$ is bijective.

Define $\eta : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ by $$\eta(m,n)=2^m (2n+1)-1$$ Then $\eta$ is bijective (You can check easily.)

We obtain $\eta \circ \xi$, which is a bijective from $F$ onto $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Using your method it can also be proved that e.g. $\mathbb R$ is countable (which is not true).

We could just start with: "let elements of $\mathbb R$ be of the form $r_i$...".

Going on with: "the rule $h(i)=r_i$ is surjective.."

---

Can you prove that $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ is countable?

Hint: $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(2,0),(1,1),(0,2),(3,0),\dots$

Further find a bijection $F\to\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

This post will be deleted.

@hi moon Thanks so much for your help! I really appreciate it.

I'm having difficulty showing η is injective.

η is injective if ∀ (m, n), (p, q) ∈ ℕ  x ℕ, if η( (m, n) ) = η( (p, q) ) then (m, n) = (p, q).

Thus suppose η( (m,n) ) = η( (p,q) ). 
Then we have:

$2^m$(2n + 1) - 1 = $2^p$(2q + 1) - 1.

$\frac{2^m}{2^p}$ = $\frac{2q + 1}{2n + 1}$.

Taking the logs of base 2 of both sides we end up with

$log_2$( $\frac{2^m}{2^p}$ ) = $log_2$( $\frac{2q + 1}{2n + 1}$ )

m - p = $log_2$(2q + 1) - $log_2$(2n + 1)

I don't know what the next step is.

Comment: $2n+1$ must divide $2q+1$ since both are odd numbers. For the same reason, $2q+1$ divide $2n+1$. Hence, $n=q$, which implies $m=p$

Comment: @himoon I understand that (2q + 1) and (2n + 1) are odd but the thing that I don't understand is how do we know that (2q + 1)/(2n + 1) is natural number?

Comment: Here is another way. Since $2n+1$ and $2p+1$ is odd, $2^m$ must be equal to $2^p$. Then this fact implies $n=p$. In my thought, this way is better. right? I used the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.(Unique factorization.)